# This content cannot be displayed in a frame - eclipse (displayHelpResource(href))

Tags: java, eclipse, x-frame-options

I'm trying to open a URL in my application through the `displayHelpResource(href)` function.
But I'm being shown the following :
**This content cannot be dispalyed in a frame**

**To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.**

I've understood that the site is blocking the Frame access. What can be done to open the desired URL using the `displayHelpResource(href)` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `noframes=true` to the href you stop frames being used

```
http:xxxxx?noframes=true
```

The `noframes=true` text is removed from the href by the help system before it is actually used.

Comment: but I want to open it in the help dialog itself. The method you've suggested is letting the URL to open in an external browser. Is there any way we can make it open in the help resource itself?

Comment: That is all there is as far as I can see